# Inno Setup: Put DLLs in a subdirectory

Tags: c++, windows, dll, inno-setup

I want to have the dependencies (a couple of DLL files) copied in a separated sub directory. After installing my program, the directory structure would look like:

- dlls/

  - a.dll
  - b.dll
- sample/
- pg.exe

The relevant part of my script is as follows:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\sample"
Name: "{app}\dll"
[Files]
Source: "pg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; icon file
;Source: "pg.ico"; DestDir: "{app}"
; sample ini and geoemtry file
Source: "geometry.xml"; DestDir: "{app}\sample"
Source: "ini.xml"; DestDir: "{app}\sample"

; DLL  
Source: "a.DLL"; DestDir: "{app}\dll"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist 
Source: "b.DLL"; DestDir: "{app}\dll"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
```

When I test my installer in a VM I get an error saying that a.DLL is not found. The problem is quickly solved if I just copy `a.DLL` from `dll/` to the directory of the executable.

- Is it necessary to put all dlls on the same level as the executable?
- Or is there a way to make the executable find its dependencies in the  subdirectory dll/?

Comment: Are you using implicit or explicit DLL linkage?

Comment: I don't know. How to find out?

Comment: Explicit linkage is achieved using `LoadLibrary` or `LoadLibraryEx` in code, implicit linkage is achieved using `dllimport`/`dllexport` statements and the DLLs must have corresponding import library (.LIB) files. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using implicit DLL linkage, then there are only several directories
where you can place the necessary DLL files. Assuming `SafeDllSearchMode` is on (which is the default since Window XP SP2), Windows loader searches DLLs in this order:

1. The directory where your executable located
2. The Windows directory
3. The Windows system directory
4. The current working directory
5. The directories listed in the PATH environment variable

For more information about search order see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

If you are using this type of linkage, I would suggest you place your DLLs in the 
same directory as your executable.

On the other hand, if you are explicitly linking to these DLL using `LoadLibrary` or
`LoadLibraryEx` APIs, here is what you can do:

1. You can call `AddDllDirectory` and pass it the path to directory that contains your
   DLLs. Make sure you call this function before you load the libraries, and make sure you
   load the libraries using `LoadLibraryEx` with flag `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS`.
2. You can retrieve the path to your executable using `GetModuleFileName` function, then 
   use it to construct absolute paths to DLLs and use these paths when calling `LoadLibrary(Ex)`.
3. You can call `SetDllDirectory` before calling `LoadLibrary(Ex)`. The problem with this
   method is that each time the `SetDllDirectory` function is called, it replaces the directory
   specified in the previous `SetDllDirectory` call. This can cause problems if you are not careful
   because some other part of code could call `SetDllDirectory` and cause failure when loading your DLLs

Comment: Thanks for indicating the places where to put the dlls. That helped.  I have implicite linkage.

Comment: The list order assumes `SafeDllSearchMode = 0 (off)` while the default has been `1 (on)` since Windows XP SP2.

Comment: @MSalters My answer did not suggest that this was the exact order, it merely stated the locations. I will however, update the answer to avoid confusion.